# Is this a parametric differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The considered ODE which is a second order homogeneous for function $y$ and a first order non-homogeneous for function $z$. Variable $u$ belong to interval $[0,\infty]$, parameter $\alpha$ to $[0,1]$. The corresponding differential equation is

\begin{equation}\label{generalform}
z~y''+\frac{1}{2}z'~y'+
\frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{z-1}{u}\Big)'~{y}=0~,
\end{equation}

the boundary conditions are
\begin{equation}\label{BC2&3}
y(1)=\sqrt{1-\alpha},~~~y'(1)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-\alpha}}~,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{BC1}
z(1)=1-\alpha~.
\end{equation}

Due to boundary conditions the variable coefficients of both differential equations depend on the parameter $\alpha$. I would like to state that the above ODE is a parametric differential equation, i.e. $z \equiv z(u,\alpha)$ and $y\equiv z(u,\alpha)$. Is it mathematically correct?

Expressed differently, the solution of DE for function $z$ defines variable coefficients of DE for function $y$. Due to boundary condition on $z$ these variable coefficients depend additionally on the boundary condition on $z$. The same is valid in the other direction ($z \leftrightarrow y$).

Comment: I've not heard of the term parametric DE. But setting an ODE with parameter-dependent initial conditions $x(t_{0}; a)$ are common in trajectory optimization, which is called the 'shooting method.'

Comment: In parametric DE solutions depend analytically on some parameter, i.e. as for example: $y''+p(x,\lambda) y'+q(x,\lambda) y=0$ , expressed differently, its variable coefficients depend not only on variable but also on some parameter.

Comment: Did you mean $y\equiv y(u, \alpha)$?

Comment: It was meant generally, but yes, regarding the question I should use $u$ Instead of $x$.

Comment: There is a differential or functional equation for $z$ missing. Without that information, the solution to the $y$ equation can be almost everything.

Comment: It is a special method of obtaining exact solutions developed by Tolman. One can postulate some $z$ and solve the second order DE for $y$. Or, one can do it otherwise and solve the first order DE on $z$. Tolma's paper https://authors.library.caltech.edu/4362/1/TOLpr39.pdf, and my formulation https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096 .

Comment: Returning back to your comment, if the missing $z$ is postulated, the variable coefficients depending on $z$ and its derivative have to be continuous functions for all $u$ and $\alpha$. This is a way of my argumentation - these coefficients have to be finite.  In physical terms it means that energy density and it derivative are everywhere finite, even when the pressure diverges (as by emergence of the black hole singularity).