# What are the conditions for maximal and global solution of a second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a second order linear homogeneous differential equation with variable coefficients depending on a parameter $p$. The equation reads
\begin{equation}
a(x,p)~y''+b(x,p)~y'+c(x,p)~y~=0,~~~~~x\in[0,\infty],~~~p\in [0,1] 
\end{equation}
and the boundary conditions are
\begin{equation}
y(x_1,p)=y_1(p),~~~~~y'(x_1,p)=y'_1(p).
\end{equation}

I am looking for the unique maximal and global solution. I presume, to ensure this I have to demand that the variable coefficients $a(x,p), b(x,p), c(x,p)$ have to be continues, **finite** functions for all $x\in[0,\infty]$ and $p\in [0,1]$. Is it mathematically correct?

Comment: Continuous is sufficient, this implies finite on all finite intervals. You need to avoid zeros of the leading coefficient  $a$, as at such singular places where the order of the DE drops the solution can also diverge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have hoped so. My question is connected to the other one, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4335266/1003573 . The equation there is the famous Einstein field equation for the static spherically symmetric metric. I try to show that the demand on metric to be maximal and global solution leads to energy density that is everywhere finite, contrary to pressure. Would you mind to name some reference that I could quote in my paper?